# Email private information appearing in Google Results

Tags: google, email, google-search

I've got a major problem in that emails sent to our clients are showing up in Google's search results. For confidentiality reasons, I can't post those links (for risk that they get indexed here), but the format is something like this

```
http://www.abc.com/xxhh1213131
```

where xxhh1213131 is a unique "token" that for each of our recipients.

Any idea how this might be happening? We have a "view as webpage" link in our emails. Could this have happened from traffic to those links?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the search engines can find the page those links are on and are not told to ignore those pages, they will index them like any other web document. `<speculation>`In your specific case they probably found them when the user went to view them. Either the browser or an extension in the browser sent tha information to Google and they then crawled those pages.`</speculation>`

If you do not want them indexed, and would like them to be removed, you need to tell the search engines to block them. There are [several ways](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8005/blocking-search-engines-to-crawl-parts-of-a-website) to do this:

> 1) Use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/)
>
> 2) Use meta tags
>
> ```
> <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
> ```
>
> 3) Use http headers
>
> ```
> Header set x-robots-tag: noindex
> ```
>
> 4) Use rel="nofollow"
>
> ```
> <a href="http://www.example.com/sample.html" rel="nofollow">Link to page I don't want indexed</a>
> ```
>
> 5) Place the content behind a login. Search engines (generally) do not
>   submit forms nor create accounts at websites.
>
> 6) Block the bots of all of the major search engines using .htaccess
>   but that would be tedious and prone to error if they change whatever
>   it is you would use to identify them (e.g. ip address, user agent).

Comment: Keep in mind that only #5 is really the secure. The other choices just hide the choices, but anyway with the right address (or a good guess) could still see the messages...

Comment: Especially the world readable robots.txt, if I see a `Disallow: /secret/mails` there, I will have a closer look. ;-)