# How can I prevent a search engine from indexing a specific file or files on my website?

Tags: search-engines, search-engine-indexing, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blocking Search Engines to Crawl Parts of a Website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8005/blocking-search-engines-to-crawl-parts-of-a-website)

In general, I want my site to be indexed, but there are certain files I don't wish to be searchable from Google, Yahoo, etc...

I know you can block your site from being indexed using a robots file, but what if I only want certain files to not be indexed?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use robots.txt too. Then you would write several disallow statements. Here are some examples:

```
Disallow: /tmp
Disallow: /logs
```

For more information see the [specification of the robots file](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).

But be aware that not every spider respects this file. So maybe you need other methods like e.g. the nofollow meta tag if you really want to be sure.