# Hiding a particulat page from search engines not to index

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt, noindex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blocking Search Engines to Crawl Parts of a Website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8005/blocking-search-engines-to-crawl-parts-of-a-website)

I have a page which i don't want search engines to index or crawl. I am not sure hat should i put in my robots.txt file to tell search engines not to crawl/index that page.

The page it itself is getting generated dynamically and do not have a predefined template for it all i know about its URL which is pre-defined and will remain unchanged.

I have this page say at

```
www.mysite.com/my-nonindexable-page/
```

Please suggest what i should do to achieve this.I am using WordPress for my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell everybody (`*`) not to crawl the URL:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /my-nonindexable-page/
```